# Consumed more salt than we have of rice

Tags: grammar

I have seen this sentence on the NYTimes, My Grandmother’s Favorite Scammer.

But this shallow perspective on aging infantilizes the elderly and neglects to preserve their dignity. They are people who have “consumed more salt than we have of rice,” as the saying goes. They deserve better.

Is there a grammar mistake in the sentence that "consumed more salt than we have of rice"?

Comment: It's not an English saying. Could it be a Chinese one?

Comment: The sentence is *grammatical*, but it is stylistically confusing.

Comment: Yes, it's a Chinese proverb. Would you mind telling me the way it is grammatical? What's the use of "of rice"

Comment: I think it should either be "consumed more of salt than we have of rice", or "consumed more salt than we have rice", or "consumed more salt than rice". This is a combination of the first two. I don't want to say whether it's grammatical or not, but it's certainly very awkward to have "more salt" and "of rice" with an "of" before "rice" and not "salt".

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly grammatical but so unusual in the way it's written that it would invite confusion.

A couple of options for making it clearer:

- They are people who have "consumed more salt than we have consumed
  rice."
- They are people who have "consumed more of salt than we have
  of rice."

Apparently the Chinese saying is, 我吃盐多过你吃米, *I have eaten more salt than you have eaten rice*.

It looks like the author of the NY Times piece may have selected the unusual phrasing from this article.

https://www.aspirantsg.com/she-has-probably-eaten-more-salt-than-you-have-eaten-rice/

> To say that someone has **eaten more salt than you have of rice**, it
>   shows that they have been around and gone through a great deal more
>   than you have and we should respect their wealth of life experience.